# PHP vs Mysql Speed in Math triangulation

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a database which contains locations (latitude and longitude) with about 5000 entries.

Now i would like to select every location which is between 50-75 miles away from a given position.

My current sql is:

```
SELECT a.ID AS ID, a.post_name, a.post_title 
FROM wp_posts a, wp_locations b 
WHERE b.post_id = a.ID 
AND 
    (3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('{$coordinates['lat']}') ) * COS( RADIANS( b.map_coords_1 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( b.map_coords_2 ) - RADIANS('{$coordinates['lng']}') ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '{$coordinates['lat']}' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( b.map_coords_1 ) ) ) ) < 75 
AND 
    ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS('{$coordinates['lat']}') ) * COS( RADIANS( b.map_coords_1 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( b.map_coords_2 ) - RADIANS('{$coordinates['lng']}') ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '{$coordinates['lat']}' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( b.map_coords_1 ) ) ) ) > 50
ORDER BY 
    ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '{$coordinates['lat']}' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( b.map_coords_1 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( b.map_coords_2 ) - RADIANS(  '{$coordinates['lng']}' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '{$coordinates['lat']}' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( b.map_coords_1 ) ) ) )
```

with `$coordinates['lat']` and `$coordinates['lng']` being the lat/lng of the position.

Now my question is: Would it be faster/better to do such calculations in PHP only?

This would mean to pull all entries (5000) into PHP and then calculate the distances?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: MySQL can use indexes, which would ordinarily prove invaluable in cutting the dataset down to a more manageable size. That said, this is actually a tiny data set, so probably won't make much difference!

Comment: @Strawberry It can't use indexes when you're using the result of a complex formula like that.

Comment: I would use `BETWEEN 51 AND 74` instead of repeating the formula.

Comment: agree with @Strawberry that the dataset is tiny enough that I wouldn't really worry about optimizing it, but, if you are using MySQL 5.6.1+ you will likely get a performance boost by using geospatial indices and the `ST_distance` function

Comment: @barmar I didn't suggest that it could, but you *can* swiftly whittle down the data set, without recourse to the formula! ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry I assumed that his alternate plan was to keep `WHERE b.post_id = a.id` in the query.

Comment: @barmar you've lost me

Comment: I agree with @Strawberry too and believe this dataset is really small to provide a difference. I'd also like to recommend something: databases are for storing data only, avoid programing something using SQL if you can. Get your data, work with it in your php, save it back. It may look like useless advice, but your code will be much more readable and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

If you add to the `WHERE` clause a "bounding box", and `INDEX(latitude)`, you can partially make use of an index, thereby decreasing the number of rows to look at.

A bounding box looks something like this:

```
AND latitude  BETWEEN $a AND $b
AND longitude BETWEEN $c AND $d
```

$a and $b are relatively straightforward -- your starting latitude - and + `75 * $miles_to_degrees (75 miles converted to latitude degrees).  It is not practical to try to say anything about "more than 50".  For longitude ($c and $d), you need`75 * $miles_to_degrees / COS($starting_latitude)`.

I agree that 5000 is hardly worth worrying about.  If you had a million rows, I would push you to [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).